# How to repopulate form data in magento if email already available

Tags: magento-1.8, forms, session

I created cumstom module for seller registration in magento.
On email validation if email is already available...my form reloading with error email already available...

On that time my form whole value goes empty....

I need to know that how to repopulate data in fields on ...error in magento..on form reloading...

my one line html is..

---

```
  <li>
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Enter Your Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="vname" id="vname" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Enter Your Name') ?>" class="input-text  required-entry" />
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is to save the info to your session, take a look at [Magento - Wiki - Custom Module with Custom Database Table](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

Note : Although this example is base off admin form it can be adjusted for any situation.

On error save to session

```
class <Namespace>_<Module>_Adminhtml_<Module>Controller extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            try {
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $<module>Model = Mage::getModel('<module>/<module>');
               ....
                 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->set<Module>Data(false);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->set<Module>Data($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
```

Display info in form

```
class <Namespace>_<Module>_Block_Adminhtml_<Module>_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
       ....
        if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->get<Module>Data() )
        {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->get<Module>Data());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->set<Module>Data(null);
        } elseif ( Mage::registry('<module>_data') ) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('<module>_data')->getData());
        }
```

Comment: and to echo on value="<?php ?>"

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides a class for handling your GET/POST requests, and it can be used like so:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('vname');
```

This should output whatever value was supplied on the previous page when the form was submitted. So for example, your PHTML can be marked up like this:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    name="vname" 
    id="vname" 
    title="<?php echo $this->__('Enter Your Name') ?>" 
    class="input-text required-entry"
    value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('vname'));" 
    />
```

Note that you can optionally specify a 2nd argument to `getParam` to serve as the default when what you are asking for cannot be found.

Comment: Post data will get destroy on form reloading (for most default magento module setup assuming controller action are "edit", "new", and "save"

Comment: Ahh yes, because of `_redirect` - good point.